# my ajax post request is called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some javascript code in my wordpress site that post an ajax request to a php file and then the file generates a pdf with a quote.

It all works, but I don't understand why the second time I submit the request (to create the second quote, basically), the ajax request then is called twice?

> the first time is correct, and it's called one time.
>
> from the second time, it's always called twice.

here's the code:

```
$('#add-to-cart-quote-email-button').on('click', function() {
  var statusIcon;
  statusIcon = $('#quote-send-spinner');
  $('.send-quote-from-cart-page-container').slideToggle();
  statusIcon.removeClass('fa fa-check');
  statusIcon.removeClass('fa fa-times');
  $('#cart-quote-email-send-button').on('click', function(e) {
    var data, email, name, quote_type, role;
    e.preventDefault();
    name = $('.send-quote-from-cart-page-container #name');
    email = $('.send-quote-from-cart-page-container #email-address');
    role = $('.send-quote-from-cart-page-container #user-role').val();
    quote_type = $('.send-quote-from-cart-page-container #quote-type').val();
    if (!name.val()) {
      console.log("empty name");
      name.addClass('invalid');
      return;
    } else {
      if (name.hasClass('invalid')) {
        name.removeClass('invalid');
      }
    }
    if (!validateEmail(email.val())) {
      console.log("invalid email");
      email.addClass('invalid');
      return;
    } else {
      if (email.hasClass('invalid')) {
        email.removeClass('invalid');
      }
    }
    console.log("sent! to email " + (email.val()) + " and name " + (name.val()));
    data = {
      name: name.val(),
      email: email.val(),
      role: role,
      quote_type: quote_type
    };
    statusIcon.addClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: 'cxecrt-success-get-link-url=&cxecrt-saved-cart-name=&cxecrt-landing-page=cart&action=save_cart_and_get_link_ajax',
      success: function(response) {
        data.cartURL = response.cart_url;
        return $.ajax({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/wp-content/themes/theme/generate_pdf_quotes/emailQuote.php',
          data: data,
          success: function() {
            console.log("success!");
            statusIcon.removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw');
            statusIcon.addClass('fa fa-check');
            return setTimeout(function() {
              return $('.send-quote-from-cart-page-container').slideToggle();
            }, 2000);
          },
          fail: function() {
            console.log("fail");
            statusIcon.removeClass('fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw');
            return statusIcon.addClass('fa fa-times');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

return;
```

I need to call the second ajax on success of the first one, as they do two completely different things and the first one is required by the second one, that it's meant to be like that and it's not (i believe) the cause of this issue

I inspected the code but I couldn't see anything wrong in here.
Any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: why do you have a nested on 'click' function ?

Comment: @NidhinChandran the first one toggle the container, the second one sends out the request

Comment: i think @Shadowfox give you the right answer

Comment: @NidhinChandran, yes, he did. Moved the second event outside from the first one and everything works fine.

Comment: @OffirPe'er i tried your idea as well, but it didn't work. The request is still submitted twice even after ading e.stopPropagation(); as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an eventHandler within the first eventHandler.

On line 1:

```
$('#add-to-cart-quote-email-button').on('click', function() {
```

On line 7:

```
$('#cart-quote-email-send-button').on('click', function(e) {
```

That's why the second time it is clicked, it calls twice. I bet if you click it a third time it calls 3x ;-)

Comment: oh ok,  fair enough. I though that events doing completely different things where fine even if nested..but apparently that's not the case :)

Comment: If you want to call some logic behind the click event of that 2nd button, use the .click() method, that will actually call the function instead of defining a handler.

Comment: I just moved the second callback outside the first one and everything now works as expected. thanks a lot for the suggestion